# Цикл for превращается в while C# 1.0

Tags: c#

Почему цикл for превращается в while? C# 1.0 написано. Я так думаю, что в тот момент там не было цикла for (но ведь это кажется бредовой мыслью, или всё же это истинно?).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем именно ты смотришь? Какие настройки?

Comment: К слову, `foreach` тоже преобразуются в while, но если ты используешь `yield`, то компилятор создаст подкласс и реализует `IEnumerable` и `IEnumerator` в нем, а метод с возвращаемым типом (в котором еще будет `yield`) будет помечен атрибутом как итератор

Comment: Цикл `for`, это на самом деле конструкция `while`, так и есть и всегда было.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я полагаю, это окошко показывает вывод декомпилятора. В этом случае, тут нечему удивляться - код, скомпилированный в инструкции для реального или виртуального процессора является более низкоуровневым, чем исходный. Определенные синтаксические конструкции исходного кода могут превращаться в одни и те же последовательности инструкций низкоуровневого.

Да даже если рассмотреть `if {} else {}` в С - при компиляции эта конструкция превращается как бы в `goto` для одного из ветвей. Просто современные декомпиляторы обычно достаточно умны, чтобы увидеть здесь конструкцию ветвлению и декомпилировать корректно.

В вашем случае цикл `for` и цикл `while` функционально эквивалентны, поэтому декомпилятор просто не может знать, какого вида цикл был в исходном коде.